# Predicting continuous output

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, curve-fitting

I'm trying to predict output per worker for given inputs of capital (physical capital), labor (human capital) & productivity. I have a data set  of several countries

```
[[ "USA", {"Capital":3.21,"Labor":1.31,"Productivity":3.17}, 2.96 ]
 [ "Norway", {"Capital":3.46,"Labor":1.27,"Productivity":2.92}, 2.72 ]
 [ "UK", {"Capital":2.21,"Labor":1.27,"Productivity":2.76}, 2.25 ]
 [ "Canada", {"Capital":2.76,"Labor":1.32,"Productivity":2.5}, 2.22 ]
 [ "Japan", {"Capital":3.53,"Labor":1.3,"Productivity":2.12}, 2.04 ]
 [ "South Korea", {"Capital":2.34,"Labor":1.22,"Productivity":2}, 1.6 ]
 [ "Mexico", {"Capital":0.87,"Labor":1.04,"Productivity":1.65}, 0.86 ]
 [ "Peru", {"Capital":0.38,"Labor":1.07,"Productivity":1.01}, 0.41 ]
 [ "India", {"Capital":0.32,"Labor":0.97,"Productivity":1.11}, 0.38 ]
 [ "Cameroon", {"Capital":0.12,"Labor":0.76,"Productivity":1.39}, 0.3 ]
 [ "Zambia", {"Capital":0.1,"Labor":0.85,"Productivity":0.44}, 0.1 ]
 [ "United-States", {"Capital":3.21,"Labor":1.31,"Productivity":3.17}, 2.96 ]
 [ "Canada", {"Capital":3.21,"Labor":1.19,"Productivity":3.28}, 2.78 ]
 [ "Italy", {"Capital":3.41,"Labor":0.85,"Productivity":3.83}, 2.47 ]
 [ "West-Germany", {"Capital":3.59,"Labor":1.05,"Productivity":2.89}, 2.42 ]
 [ "France", {"Capital":3.5,"Labor":0.87,"Productivity":3.57}, 2.42 ]
 [ "United-Kingdom", {"Capital":2.86,"Labor":1.06,"Productivity":3.2}, 2.15 ]
 [ "Hong-Kong", {"Capital":2.38,"Labor":0.96,"Productivity":3.53}, 1.8 ]
 [ "Singapore", {"Capital":3.31,"Labor":0.71,"Productivity":3.42}, 1.79 ]
 [ "Japan", {"Capital":3.59,"Labor":1.04,"Productivity":2.09}, 1.74 ]
 [ "Mexico", {"Capital":2.78,"Labor":0.71,"Productivity":2.94}, 1.28 ]
 [ "Argentina", {"Capital":3.06,"Labor":0.89,"Productivity":2.05}, 1.24 ]
 [ "USSR.", {"Capital":3.95,"Labor":0.95,"Productivity":1.48}, 1.23 ]
 [ "India", {"Capital":2.27,"Labor":0.6,"Productivity":0.85}, 0.25 ]
 [ "China", {"Capital":2.86,"Labor":0.83,"Productivity":0.34}, 0.18 ]
 [ "Kenya", {"Capital":2.4,"Labor":0.6,"Productivity":0.52}, 0.17 ]
 [ "Zaire", {"Capital":1.6,"Labor":0.53,"Productivity":0.51}, 0.1 ]]
```

Each row represent country name, inputs (capital, labor, productivity) & output.
Now I want to be able from given inputs say

```
{"Capital":1.1,"Labor":0.4,"Productivity":0.3}
```

to predict how much output will the country produce.

So far I've looked at two neural network implementations http://github.com/harthur/brain   which gives me bad predictions (or I'm using it/training it badly), and http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs which I don't know how to use for continuous data.

I don't know are the neural networks right approach,or maybe different method/ library are more fitting for my problem, maybe surface fitting or whatever. I just want to create some bastard Solow model that roughly fits the data points I have.

Comment: Get coefficients using R and lm function: lm(out~. , data=mydata)

Comment: @whuber I don't have idea how to narrow it down. What I need is  any method to learn from historical data and predict from new inputs.I've looked at two neural network implementations https://github.com/harthur/brain bad predictions (or me using it wrong), and http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/ don't know how to use it for continuous data. So I'm not sure are neural networks even right approach.

Comment: Predicting one value based on observations of other values comprises a great deal of statistics. There wouldn't be enough space even to list all their *names* in an answer! To focus your question you need at least to explain what these data are and provide a context for understanding why you are making predictions and evaluating the quality of those predictions.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't simply using standard regression methods?

Comment: Because I forgot all the statistics in 14 years of not using it. The only tools I have now are magic (libraries) or brute force and ignorance.   Any more specific pointers/links for my problem 3 independent parameters -> 1 dependent will be appreacited

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code in R for linear regression, assuming you have the object as a dataframe X,

  `Capital Labor Productivity Output
    3.21  1.31         3.17   2.96
    3.46  1.27         2.92   2.72
    2.21  1.27         2.76   2.25
    2.76  1.32         2.50   2.22
    3.53  1.30         2.12   2.04
    2.34  1.22         2.00   1.60`

Then you can just use the simple linear regression

```
fit = lm(Output~., data = X)
```

To predict on newdata which doesn't have the Output, you just use predict

```
predict(fit, newdata)
```